# Counter inkrementing

Tags: javascript, performance, class

so I just learn how to code in JS, so i just want to warn you that my code may looks very awful for you.

I want a "class" that counts how often a number has been counted.

Example:

```
counter = new Counter();
counter.count(1);
counter.count(1);
counter.count(3);
```

Calling the getCounts gives the result:

```
counter.getCounts();
> 1: 2, 3: 1
```

My code works, but i have two problems.

1. Since I store it in an array, I can output the numbers not in order, but in the order they were called.
2. I don't think it's a pretty solution.

My code:

```
class Counter {
    constructor(arr = []) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    count(number) {
        var posNumber = [];
        var evenNumCheck = false;
        var exactPos;
        //Check if have the number already in the array
        for (var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
            if (this.arr[i] === number) {
                posNumber.push(i);
            }
        }
        //posNumber we have the position of all the numbers that match our argument number
        // we check which of them has an even position, only this can be the number we want
        // since we save [number,count; number,count]
        for (var i = 0; i < posNumber.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) {
                evenNumCheck = true;
                exactPos = i;
            }
        }
        if (evenNumCheck) {
            this.arr[exactPos + 1]++;
        } else {
            this.arr.push(number);
            this.arr.push(1);
        }
    }

    getCounts() {
        var string = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i += 2) {
            if (i + 2 >= this.arr.length) {
                string += this.arr[i] + ': ' + this.arr[i + 1];
            } else {
                string += this.arr[i] + ': ' + this.arr[i + 1] + ', ';
            }
        }
        console.log(string);
    }
}
```

Do you think this solution is ok or are there better solutions for it, which might also output the numbers in order?

Comment: Use an object as a key value store where key is a number and value is the frequency of that number

Comment: Thanks for replying. Does this work like in Java? Will take a look

Comment: Please don't delete the contents of your question after it's been answered. Next time it's likely to be flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way is to use an object as said by @Orkhan Alikhanov

```js
class Counter {
  constructor () {
    this.dic = {}
  }
  count (number) {
    if (number in this.dic) {
      this.dic[number]++
    } else {
      this.dic[number] = 1
    }
  }

  getCounts () {
    // instead of doing the trailing comma stuff
    // make an array of string and join the array
    const out = Object.entries(this.dic).map(entry => entry.join(':')).join(',')
    console.log(out)
  }
}
const counter = new Counter()
counter.count(1)
counter.count(1)
counter.count(2)
counter.getCounts()
```

You may prefer using a Map since semantically you just want to map a number to a count.

```js
class Counter {
  constructor () {
    this.dic = new Map()
  }
  count (number) {
    const count = this.dic.get(number)
    this.dic.set(number, count ? count + 1 : 1)
  }

  getCounts () {
    const out = [...this.dic.entries()].map(entry => entry.join(':')).join(',')
    console.log(out)
  }
}
const counter = new Counter()
counter.count(1)
counter.count(1)
counter.count(2)
counter.getCounts()
```

Finally, if you want the number printed not in the order they were inserted but with the "int" order, you have to [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the entries:

```js
class Counter {
  constructor () {
    this.dic = new Map()
  }
  count (number) {
    const count = this.dic.get(number)
    this.dic.set(number, count ? count + 1: 1)
  }

  getCounts () {
    const out = [...this.dic.entries()]
      .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]) // sort by first key (which is the number)
      .map(entry => entry.join(':'))
      .join(',')
    console.log(out)
  }
}
const counter = new Counter()
counter.count(2) // insert 2 before
counter.count(1)
counter.count(1)
counter.getCounts()
```